# use local storage to remember the high score javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, local-storage

I am building a simple tapping game as practice but I can't make it remember the top score. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript1.js"></script>
<link type= "text/css" rel= "stylesheet" href= "firstcss.css">
</head>
</head>
<body>
<div id= "div1">
<button onclick= "myFunction()"  id= "something">GO
</button>
</div>
<div id= "div2">
<p id= "paragraph">0</p>
</div>
<p id= "don"></p>
<p id= "record"></p>
<p id= "add"></p>
<script>
var cool = 1;
var best= 0;

function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML= "Keep Tapping";
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML= cool;
cool++;
var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
setTimeout(function(){
var ooo= cool-1;
document.getElementById("don").innerHTML=  cool-1; 
var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
var child = document.getElementById("something");
parent.removeChild(child);
var parent1 = document.getElementById("div2");
var child1 = document.getElementById("paragraph");
parent1.removeChild(child1);
if(ooo > best){
ooo === best;   
localStorage.setItem("hello", best);
document.getElementById("add").innerHTML= localStorage.getItem("hello");
}
else{
document.getElementById("record").innerHTML= "no new record";
}


}, 3000);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think that the problem is the if statement or the localStorage in the if statement could someone tell me how I can store the best score thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here every time **variable best is assigned to 0**. variable **best should depend on localstorage variable**.

**Modified code for assigning best variable**

```
if(localStorage.getItem("hello") == null) {
    var best = localStorage.setItem("hello", 0);
}else {
    var best = localStorage.getItem("hello");
}
```

Find the complete code here below...

http://jsfiddle.net/ptfmpedo/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you were trying to do this instead:

```
if(ooo > best) {
   best = ooo;
   localStorage.setItem("hello", best);  
   .........
}
```

Use assignment instead of triple equals.

This your code after my change:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript1.js"></script>
<link type= "text/css" rel= "stylesheet" href= "firstcss.css">
</head>
</head>
<body>
<div id= "div1">
<button onclick= "myFunction()"  id= "something">GO
</button>
</div>
<div id= "div2">
<p id= "paragraph">0</p>
</div>
<p id= "don"></p>
<p id= "record"></p>
<p id= "add"></p>
<script>
var cool = 1;
var best= 0;

function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML= "Keep Tapping";
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML= cool;
cool++;
var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
setTimeout(function(){
var ooo= cool-1;
document.getElementById("don").innerHTML=  cool-1; 
var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
var child = document.getElementById("something");
parent.removeChild(child);
var parent1 = document.getElementById("div2");
var child1 = document.getElementById("paragraph");
parent1.removeChild(child1);
if(ooo > best){
best = ooo;   
localStorage.setItem("hello", best);
document.getElementById("add").innerHTML= localStorage.getItem("hello");
}
else{
document.getElementById("record").innerHTML= "no new record";
}


}, 3000);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your line after the if is: ooo===best, change it to best = ooo and it works

Comment: Assignment is where you assign a variable a value using one equal sign.

Comment: I want it to show if the score that was just made is bigger than the previous best score and if it is i want it to say new record then the score. if the score is not beaten i want it to say the best score.#